# Скрипт python для проверки status_code URL

Tags: python

Всем привет
Подскажите, пожалуйста, пытаюсь сделать запрос к вебсайту 2 функцией app_request и хочу, чтоб если статус доступности сайта был 200, он возвращал 1 , если другой то 2, в первой функции get_status_app пытаюсь в зависимости от return  app_request вывести app1 или app2 , для записи в метрику,   что я делаю не так в коде, почему у меня не работает. я совсем новичок, поэтому извиняюсь

```
def get_status_app():
    url_list = ('http://google.com')
    for url in url_list:
        status_app = (1):
        if  result_app == app_request[1]:
           print('app1')
           return 1
        else:
            print('app2')
            return 0
get_status_app()

def app_request():

    try:
        resp = requests.get('http://google.com')
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            print('1')
            return 1
        else:
            print('2')
            return 0
    except:
        print('2')
        return 0
app_request()
```

Comment: return 'app1' , return 'app2' ,return 1, return 2, return 2

Comment: нужно во второй функции заменить ?

Comment: заменить сверху в низ в качестве  ориентира print('') Что в print('') то и return

Comment: мне кажется я не так вызываю вторую функцию в первой, как мне ее вызвать, чтоб первая функция знала значение которое вернула вторая ?

Answer (score 0):

Замечание по коду : Все функций располагаются сверху, основной код внизу после фунцкций, `if result_app == app_request[1]` неверный вызов функций надо `app_request()` даже если сделаем так `if result_app == app_request():` все равно не рабочий код, так как `result_app` не присвоенно значение. Что это `status_app = (1):`? тут у нас что `url_list = ('http://google.com')`? судя по названию и по логики кода список `url_list = list('http://google.com')` или `url_list = ['http://google.com']`

```
import requests


def get_status_app():
    url_list = ['http://google.com']
    for url in url_list:
        # status_app = (1)
        if app_request() == 1:
            return 'app1'
        else:
            return 'app2'


def app_request():
    try:
        resp = requests.get('http://google.com')
        if resp.status_code == 200:
            return 1
        else:
            return 2
    except:
        return 2


print(get_status_app())

'app1'
```

альтернативный вариант

```
import requests

url_list = ['http://google.com', "https://yandex.ru"]
dct = {}
for url in url_list:
    try:
        resp = requests.get(url)
        status = True if resp.status_code == 200 else False
    except Exception:
        status = True

    dct[url] = status

print(dct)
for key in dct:
    print(key, 'Status:', 'Ok' if dct[key] else 'No')
# print(*(f"{key} Status: {'Ok' if dct[key] else 'No'}" for key in dct), sep='\n')

{'http://google.com': True, 'https://yandex.ru': True}
http://google.com Status: Ok
https://yandex.ru Status: Ok
```

Comment: Сергей, спасибо большое за помощь, пойду протестирую

Comment: @DmitriiSeleznev По больше практики и все у вас получится. Я практикуюсь на этом ресурсе отвечая на вопросы. Даже если и не отвечаю, присматривую интересные решения, и стараюсь их применять в своем коде :)